# How to send data to Kinesis Data Firehose using the AWS JavaScript SDK v3?

Tags: aws-sdk-js, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to send JSON data to Kinesis Data Firehose, where it will be delivered to an S3 bucket.

It works with AWS SDK v2:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

// Full config not shown.
AWS.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-1'
});

const Firehose = new AWS.Firehose();
const params = {
  DeliveryStreamName: 'MY-STREAM-NAME',
  Record: {
    Data: JSON.stringify({
      key: "test",
      value: "hello world"
    }),
  },
};
    
Firehose.putRecord(params, () => {});
```

The `Data` value I see in the HTTP traffic is `eyJrZXkiOiJ0ZXN0IiwidmFsdWUiOiJoZWxsbyB3b3JsZCJ9` which is exactly my payload, stringified and Base64-encoded.

However, it does not work with AWS SDK v3:

```js
import { FirehoseClient, PutRecordCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-firehose";

// Full config not shown.
const config = {
  region: "us-east-1"
};

const client = new FirehoseClient(config);
const input = {
  DeliveryStreamName: "MY-STREAM-NAME",
  Record: {
    Data: JSON.stringify({
      key: "test",
      value: "hello world"
    })
  },
};

const command = new PutRecordCommand(input);
const response = await client.send(command);
console.log(response);
```

Now when I check the HTTP traffic, the `Data` value is `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA` which is clearly wrong.

I have checked lots of documentation and examples ([1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-aws-sdk-client-firehose/Class/PutRecordCommand/), [2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-firehose/classes/putrecordcommand.html), [3](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javascriptv3/example_code/kinesis/src/kinesis-example.js)), but they are not helpful.

How do I send JSON data to Firehose using AWS SDK v3?

Comment: Did you try sending data in `Buffer`? Like `Data: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({key: "test", value: "hello world" }))`

Comment: @RonakShah - I am not using Node.js. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Then should try this

`Data: new TextEncoder().encode(JSON.stringify({key: "test", value: "hello world" }))`

Comment: That seems to work, thanks. If you post an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send JSON data to Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose using the AWS SDK v3, you need to encode the data properly. In the v3 SDK, the `Data` field should be a `Uint8Array` or `Blob` object, not a string. You should encode your JSON data using `TextEncoder` to achieve the desired result. Here's how you can do it:

```js
import { FirehoseClient, PutRecordCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-firehose";

// Full config not shown.
const config = {
  region: "us-east-1"
};

const client = new FirehoseClient(config);
const jsonData = {
  key: "test",
  value: "hello world"
};

const input = {
  DeliveryStreamName: "MY-STREAM-NAME",
  Record: {
    Data: new TextEncoder().encode(JSON.stringify(jsonData))
  },
};

const command = new PutRecordCommand(input);

try {
  const response = await client.send(command);
  console.log(response);
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error sending data to Firehose:", error);
}
```

In this code, we first create a `Uint8Array` using `TextEncoder().encode()` to properly encode the JSON data. Then, we pass this `Uint8Array` as the `Data` field in the `Record` object when creating the `PutRecordCommand`.

This should send your JSON data correctly to Kinesis Data Firehose using AWS SDK v3.